# Getting appended values in URL using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, access-token

I am new to ruby.

In my routes I have,

```
match "path/:provider/callback" => 'Example#sample'
```

I have a ruby controller called ExamplesController. It's code is,

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController 
def sample
   binding.pry     
   render "/sample/applications/callback" and return    
 end
```

A app from Microsoft live is sending access token to this controller such as

```
http://localhost:3000/path/onedrive/callback#access_token={access_token}.
```

My question is how can I programatically get this Access token in ruby and from what parameter?

Note: I have used binding.pry and checked the value of params. it is

```
{"controller"=>"examples", "action"=>"sample", "provider"=>"onedrive"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the token is sent as a hash ( like you've shown in the question ) then there's no possible way for the server to know it, because it's never sent to the browser, it's only intended for javascript to use, using the method `location.hash`

if you really want to then you need the javascript to send it to the server by it self, in an ajax request or something.

Comment: You are absouletely right. It was intended for a Javascript to read and open onedrive file picker. But, I am doing some testing so I want to grab that access token programatically. So. are you saying there is no way in ruby to do that.

Comment: like i said, rails is never receiving this token, if you want you could add your own js that checks if there's a hash in the url and send it to a path in your app.

Comment: @Rocky29: Fragment identifiers never get sent to the server. Period. There is no way in Ruby or Rails or any other existing or yet-to-be-invented language or framework to process data on the server that never gets sent to the server. That's just basic web programming 101. Fragment identifiers are for the client.